# missing right parenthesis SQL

Tags: oracle

I am new to SQL.

I am trying to create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE account
(AccountNo NUMBER(2) PRIMARY KEY,
AccountType VARCHAR(1) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES account_type(TypeCode),
CustomerRef NUMBER(2) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES bank_customer(CustomerRef),
DateOpened DATE,
CurrentBalence NUMBER(6,2),
OverdraftLimit NUMBER(5,2));
```

However it comes up with: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
I know for a fact that you can have to foreign keys, so that's not the problem. Could someone give me a had with the solution of creating the table?

Comment: you need to say foreign key references primarytable(col)

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple `FK`s but you are not defining them correctly.  There's more to it than just placing `FOREIGN KEY` in a column definition. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm

Comment: What tables and columns do `AccountType, CustomerRef` reference?

Comment: @radar I have done this. but still the same message: CREATE TABLE account
(AccountNo NUMBER(2) PRIMARY KEY,
AccountType VARCHAR(1) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES account_type(TypeCode),
CustomerRef NUMBER(2) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES bank_customer(CustomerRef),
DateOpened DATE,
CurrentBalence NUMBER(6,2),
OverdraftLimit NUMBER(5,2));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the foreign keys with `REFERENCES`. In the below snippet, replace `AccountTypeTable` and `CustomerRefTable` with the correct table names and replace `typeColumn` and `refColumn` with the correct column names in those tables these match to.

**UPDATE**

I added in the correct values from your comment on another answer

```
CREATE TABLE account (
    AccountNo NUMBER(2) PRIMARY KEY,
    AccountType VARCHAR(1),
    CustomerRef NUMBER(2),
    DateOpened DATE,
    CurrentBalence NUMBER(6,2),
    OverdraftLimit NUMBER(5,2),
    CONSTRAINT account_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (AccountType) REFERENCES Account_Type(TypeCode),
    CONSTRAINT account_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (CustomerRef) REFERENCES Bank_Customer(CustomerRef));
```

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key actually has to refer to something. In your case you have to tell Oracle what AccountType and CustomerRef refer to. Usually it looks as follows:

```
AccountType VARCHAR(1) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TABLE_NAME(COLUMN_NAME)
```

Of course, you have to replace TABLE_NAME and COLUMN_NAME with the name of the table and the name of the column you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

There are two notations you can use when declaring constraints:

1) inline (a constraint):

```
CREATE TABLE account
(AccountNo NUMBER(2) PRIMARY KEY,
AccountType VARCHAR(1) REFERENCES account_type(TypeCode),
CustomerRef NUMBER(2) REFERENCES bank_customer(CustomerRef),
DateOpened DATE,
CurrentBalence NUMBER(6,2),
OverdraftLimit NUMBER(5,2));
```

2) out-of-line

```
CREATE TABLE account
(
AccountNo NUMBER(2) PRIMARY KEY,
AccountType VARCHAR(1),
CustomerRef NUMBER(2),
DateOpened DATE,
CurrentBalence NUMBER(6,2),
OverdraftLimit NUMBER(5,2),
FOREIGN KEY(AccountType) REFERENCES account_type(TypeCode),
FOREIGN KEY(CustomerRef) REFERENCES account_type(TypeCode)
);
```

In both cases you can prepend the constraint declaration with `CONSTRAINT <name>` to give your name to a constraint, otherwise Oracle assigns its own name.

inline notation is applied to a column where the constraint is declared, out-of-line is applied to the table. There slight differences in syntax + some restrictions, for example you cannot declare out-of-line NULL constraint.

You can use inline and out-of-line syntax in CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE. Refer to Oracle documentation for more information

Answer (score 0):

you are missing foreign key syntax...

```
CREATE TABLE account
(AccountNo NUMBER(2) PRIMARY KEY (P_ID),
AccountType VARCHAR(1) FOREIGN KEY (F1_ID) REFERENCES <table_name>(field_name>),
CustomerRef NUMBER(2) FOREIGN KEY (F2_ID) REFERENCES <table_name>(field_name>),
DateOpened DATE,
CurrentBalence NUMBER(6,2),
OverdraftLimit NUMBER(5,2));
```

Comment: have done this. but still saying the same message: CREATE TABLE account
(AccountNo NUMBER(2) PRIMARY KEY,
AccountType VARCHAR(1) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES account_type(TypeCode),
CustomerRef NUMBER(2) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES bank_customer(CustomerRef),
DateOpened DATE,
CurrentBalence NUMBER(6,2),
OverdraftLimit NUMBER(5,2));